# Is it required to keep return in js function()

Tags: javascript, function

Is it required to keep return in js function()

```
function EshopProcessOrder() {
    window.location = "http://www.google.com/";
    return false;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Nope. No need to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. If you don't want to `return` anything from the `function` you can skip it. But by default `undefined` will be returned.

So, if you don't have `return` statement in the `function` javascript will by default add `return undefined` at the end of the function.

`return false` is used to stop the default action of the element and stop the event propagation to the ancestors.

In your case,

```
function EshopProcessOrder() {
    window.location = "http://www.google.com/";
    return false;
}
```

`return false` will never executed, since the page is redirected before reaching that statement.